# ld flag -macosx_version_min doesn't work

Tags: macos, compilation, linker, ld

I try this:

```
$ ld -macosx_version_min 10.11 -lc++ -lSystem a.o -o main
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.10
ld: warning: object file (a.o) was built for newer OSX version (10.11) than being linked (10.10)
```

How do i declare -macosx_version_min? It seems the solution should be easy, but whatever I do, it doesn't seem to work.

However when I leave out the `-macosx_version_min` part, it will give me a linker error for `start`. How can that even be?

Comment: I'm seeing this warning as well in the presence of the option under different circumstances. Not sure what's triggering it, but I'd guess it's a bug.